# memory mapping for Union

Tags: c++, unions

```
union Data {
    int a;
    double b;
    Data(){
        a = 1;
        b = 0.5;
    }
};

int main(){

    Data udata;
    udata.a = 999999999;
    cout << udata.a << "\t" << udata.b << endl;
    return 0;
}


result: 999999999       0.5
```

I knew `a` and `b` are mapped to the same memory location, but why `b` is still equal to 0.5 after assigning 999999999 to `a`.

Comment: You tagged both `C++` and `C`. These are different languages. In C++ your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: `[C++]` Reading the non-active member of a union is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: So even C++14 or C++17 is the same?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that their different data-types have separated them. Your `union` code defines `a` as integer & `b` as double and `b`'s value is still unchanged even after having same memory addresses. If you set either `a` as double or `b` as integer, you'll get the values changed together..

Look at the following:

```
union Data {
    int a;
    int b; // changed double to int

    Data() {
        a = 1;
        b = 0.5;
    }
};
```

Hope it helps you understand.